# Store attributes in deleted couchbase documents

Tags: swift, couchbase-lite

I want to be able to save the data inside deleted records in a Couchbase Lite application. According [the couchbase lite documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html#deleting) I should be able to save a `deleted_at` attribute along with all of the current attributes using this code (slightly modified for a newer era of Swift syntax):

```
do {
    try document.update { (newRev) -> Bool in
        newRev.isDeletion = true
        newRev["deleted_at"] = currentTimeStamp

        print("Document deleted at: \(document["deleted_at"])")
        // prints "Document deleted at: nil"

        print("Revision deleted at: \(newRev["deleted_at"])")
        // prints "Revision deleted at: Optional(2016-03-14)"
        return true
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    self.handleError(error)
}
```

However, if I try to access the attributes later, they don't exist:

```
print("Deleted: \(document.isDeleted)")
// prints "Deleted: Optional(true)"

print("Deleted at: \(document["deleted_at"])")  
// prints "Deleted at: nil"
```

I'm pretty sure this should print the timestamp associated with the `deleted_at` attribute.

I thought that maybe couchbase doesn't allow accessing data from deleted records, but restoring the record doesn't allow access either:

```
do {
    try document.update { (newRev) -> Bool in
        newRev.isDeletion = false

        print("Document deleted at: \(document["deleted_at"])")
        // prints "Document deleted at: nil"

        print("Revision deleted at: \(newRev["deleted_at"])")
        // prints "Revision deleted at: nil"
        return true
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    self.handleError(error)
}

print("Deleted: \(document.isDeleted)")
// prints "Deleted: Optional(false)"

print("Deleted at: \(document["deleted_at"])")  
// prints "Deleted at: nil"
```

Is there something I can do to get this to work?

Comment: Does the property show up inside the update block?

Comment: @borrrden Yes, it does. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I actually meant the second update block, not the first one.

Comment: @borrrden No, I can't access the properties inside the second update block.

Comment: Does this happen when you do all of these actions right in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBLDocument doesn't normally load a deleted revision. Most of the time, if a document's been deleted the developer considers it gone, so `CBLDocument.currentRevision` will return nil instead of returning the "tombstone" revision. This then affects the property accessors, which call `currentRevision`.

If you want to get the tombstone revision anyway, because you stored data in it, you can use other accessors like `getLeafRevisions` or `getRevisionHistory`.

(FYI, I wrote this code, so this is probably the authoritative answer :)